# To whom does 'he' refer to in Mark 1:10?

Tags: jesus, mark, referent-identification

Mark 1:10 (KJV):

> 10 And straightway coming up out of the water, ***he*** saw the heavens opened, and the Spirit like a dove descending upon him:

There seems to be some ambiguity in the above text. I'm not sure whether "he" refers to John the Baptist, or Jesus who was being baptized?

Answer (score 2):

> 8  I indeed have baptized you with water: but **he** shall baptize you with the Holy Ghost.
> 9 ¶  And it came to pass in those days, that Jesus came from Nazareth
> of Galilee, and was baptized of John in Jordan. 10  And straightway
> coming up out of the water, **he** saw the heavens opened, and the Spirit
> like a dove descending upon **him**: 11  And there came a voice from
> heaven, saying, **Thou** art my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased. 12
> And immediately the Spirit driveth **him** into the wilderness.

John is incidental to the story. Jesus is the focus as illustrated by bolding the pronouns.
Jesus came out of the water. John was not immersed during Jesus's baptism.
Jesus saw the heavens opened.
The dove landed on Jesus
The voice addressed Jesus "thou".
Jesus went to the wilderness.

It would be really grammatically odd to say that John saw the heavens opened.

If the question asked "did John see it too?" the answer would be 'yes' as Polyhat is correct. But the question concerns what Mark recorded. Mark only records Jesus seeing it. This does not mean that John did not.

Why would John think it more important to record John's testimony rather than that of Jesus via Mark? Since Jesus's testimony is already recorded, John adds the second witness to the event.

Comment: It would not be odd at all to say that John saw the heavens opened.  God allows humans to witness this, and it is for a purpose.  Jesus himself recognized John as the greatest prophet (Luke 7:28).  If Moses had seen God on the mountain, what was to prevent John from witnessing the heavens opened?  Stephen, too, saw the heavens opened.  "And said, Behold, I see the heavens opened, and the Son of man standing on the right hand of God." (Acts 7:56).

Comment: If the question was asking generically can men see the heavens opened I would agree. However, the question is in the context of the verse. There is nothing there to indicate that "he" was referring to John. Would you propose that John saw it and Jesus didn't? If they both saw it, wouldn't it say "they".

Comment: My response to your question ended up being too long for a comment, and I saw fit to add it as an answer here.  Please see that in answer to your questions.

Comment: @Polyhat John certainly "saw the heavens opened." While I agree that John *could* be the "he", the NASB seems to have captured this well (IMO), **Mark 1:10**: "Immediately coming up out of the water, **He** saw the heavens opening, and the Spirit like a dove descending upon **Him**" (emphasis added).  You mentioned Stephen. His (Stephen's) case is especially interesting in that he was destined to perish either by 1) stoning, or 2) having *seen the Father* (cf. Ex. 33:20). This was a no-win situation that few may ever have experienced: death from a mob or death through God Himself! :-)

Comment: @Xeno Stephen did not see the Father, and did not die from such.  See John 1:18.  Your NASB is interpreting, not translating, and I think they got this one wrong, as is evidenced via John's account of the event.

Comment: @Polyhat My intent wasn't really to disagree with you. One thing I *will* mention is **Acts 7:56**: “'Look,' [Stephen] said, 'I see heaven open and the Son of Man standing at **the right hand of God**.'” "God" mentioned here is the Father. I'm not necessarily saying that he died because of this; the Jews were doing a great job all by themselves. I'm often surprised that people deny anyone saw God: **Ex. 24:9-10**:  "[Moses went up, along with seventy of the elders], and they saw the God of Israel... under His feet... a pavement of sapphire..." Yes, they saw God -- just not God the Father.

Comment: @Xeno John 1:18 could not be more clear that "no man hath seen God at ANY time."  Either you believe it, or you don't.  And who is God?  The scriptures are plain that the Father is God, and only the Father is God.  I agree that there are texts which are translated as saying people have seen God, but those are cases of "lost in translation."  The word _Elohim_ in Hebrew does not mean "God" as we use it today.  It is more akin to "divine being," as even angels and people are called _elohim_ in places, depending on context.

Comment: @Polyhat I'm afraid that we'll never see eye-to-eye on this either. **Ex. 33:11**: "Thus **the LORD used to speak to Moses face to face, just as a man speaks to his friend**" (emphasis added). No doubt, you'll have some clever retort to the plain language of this passage. I would too if I rejected Christ as God, but *that* is exactly who Moses spoke to "face to face, just as a man speaks to his friend." Does a man speak to his friend in a cloud or from a whirlwind, or -- well, use your imagination.

Comment: @Xeno _Speaking_ and _seeing_ are two different things.  Remember that in that same chapter, God covers Moses' face as He passes by so that Moses does NOT see His face, and sees only His backside.  Do you call this a "clever retort"?  I'm not trying to be clever.  I want to have a correct understanding of the truth, don't you? "And it shall come to pass, while my glory passeth by, that I will put thee in a cleft of the rock, and will cover thee with my hand while I pass by: And I will take away mine hand, and thou shalt see my back parts: **but my face shall not be seen.**" (Exodus 33:22-23)

Comment: @Polyhat Please understand: I'm not trying to be confrontational. I cited Ex. 33:11 expressly because, when contrasted with 33:20, we see two very different circumstances. From my point of view (Trinitarian) this makes sense because Christ (not Jesus the Man) *has existed forever* as the Word. He is the One to have spoken the universe into existence and is the One Who spoke to Adam/Eve (Gen. 3), Hagar (Gen. 16), Abraham (Gen. 18), and Moses - face to face. There are many other examples. Based on my belief, God *could* speak to many people, and did so as the Preincarnate Christ.

Comment: @Polyhat Let me say one last thing, again not trying to be contentious. Suppose I tell you that I regularly speak to someone. I then follow that up with "face-to-face." Would not immediately understand that we were not only speaking, but that we were conversing directly? Is that not what Exodus 33:11 is telling us? Why add "face-to-face" if that's a lie, that Moses really spoke to God in a cloud, or in a mist, or from a whirlwind. No, he says "face-to-face **just as a man speaks to his friend**." How can this be misinterpreted as anything other than exactly what it says?

Comment: @Xeno If you study Hebrew and learn its idioms and figures of speech, you may find some clues there.  I'm not an expert with Hebrew, but I've studied it and find it fascinating.  For example, when God says He is "longsuffering," the Hebrew actually says **God's nose is slow.**  The word "face" in Hebrew can be applied to surface (face of the earth/waters/ground/etc.), presence (before/in front of), etc.  The use of "face" does not require that one is _seeing_ the face eye-to-eye. In Moses' case, we know that he did NOT see God's face, both because God specifies that He hid it and by John 1:18.

Comment: @Polyhat I just make one more point then. Trinitarians such as myself believe that Christ and the Father are two separate personalities. Paul tells **1 Tim. 2:5**: "For there is one God, and one mediator also between God and men, *the man Christ Jesus*". Well, we know that God the Father is also God, but no one can see Him and live. The other, Christ, can be seen by human beings without lethal consequences. It is this Figure that I believe Moses spoke to "face-to-face as a man speaks to his friend." I'm afraid I'm unwilling to accept that the translators could possibly get this so wrong.

Comment: @Xeno The motto of Hebrew University is "The Bible does not need to be rewritten, but it needs to be reread."  I agree with that.  You are misreading 1 Tim. 2:5 to think it says that _the man Christ Jesus_ is God.  Clearly, Jesus, _as a man_, was NOT God.  The text is actually asserting this--identifying two parties: God, and a human mediator (who is not God).  Why would God mediate to God?  Your reading of the verse makes no logical sense at all.  By the way, I believe that God was _in Christ_ (see 2 Corinthians 5:19), but humanity was never and can never be God, Christ's humanity included.

Comment: @Polyhat OK. One last thing then. If all the idioms and figures of speech are totally different from the translator's words, how then could we understand *any of it at all?* Another contributor absolutely insists that statements like **2 Peter 3:10**: "But the day of the Lord will come like a thief, in which **the heavens will pass away with a roar and the elements will be destroyed with intense heat, and the earth and its works will be burned up**" don't mean what they say, but they **do**. The Creation will be destroyed. Words have meaning, and God expects us to understand those meanings.

Comment: @Xeno Yes, I fully agree that words have meaning and God expects us to understand those meanings.  This is why I do not go around speaking of "Paul the Spirit" based on a misreading of 1 Corinthians 5:3 anymore than one should speak of "God the Spirit" based on a misreading of the Bible.  It is actually _spiritualism_ to reference one's spirit as a separate entity to one's person.  Trinitarians are ignorantly pantheists, because if God's Spirit is actually a separate being, as they suppose, then it is very God Himself that dwells in all nature and all nature is "God."

Comment: @Polyhat I suspect that Hebrew University has no place for Christ. I could be wrong. Let's understand that God does not expect the average person to know 3 or 4 languages to simply read His Word. The eternal fate of every human on earth depends on understanding the Bible. There is no way I can accept that the words we read do not read that way. Matt. 24:35: "Heaven and earth will pass away, but My words will not pass away." If all you say is true, and the words **do not** mean what they say, then they have "passed away." They are meaningless. I don't believe that for one second.

Comment: @Xeno Care to guess how many languages Jesus knew?  Is he our Example?  God expects us to be intelligent and to use the minds with which He has endowed us.

Comment: @Polyhat Being a multilingual polyglot is not a prerequisite for reading the Bible. Christ knew *all* languages. I'm hard-pressed to think of anything Jesus could not do. **John 10:18**: "No one has taken it away from Me, but I lay it down on My own initiative. I have authority to lay it down, and I have authority to take it up again." If you do not accept the deity of Christ, then I don't expect any of this makes sense to you. The Christ (God), was God the Father's representative, His Intercessor between deity and humanity. Christ was, **and had to be**, the God-Man to represent both parties.

Comment: (Wow, I suppose we've both explored the question: "To whom does 'he' refer to in Mark 1:10?" in some detail by now!) :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Bible is not clear as to whom "he saw the heavens torn apart" is referring.  It is clear that in Mark 1:10 the first "he" and ending "him" are referring to Jesus.  However, it is presumable that both Jesus and John saw the heavens torn apart.  When  something descends upon someone, that person becomes unable to physically "see" it at some point.  Further, it seems illogical that God would hide the descent of the Spirit from John.  Luke 1:39-45 tells us that while she was still early in pregnancy,  Mary the Mother of Jesus visited her aunt and John leapt in Elizabeth's womb and Elizabeth was filled with the Holy Spirit.  The Bible is quite clear that John was a Holy man in his own right.

Comment: We're in agreement with most of what you said. However, the NASB (which I believe is a superior translation) has, **Mark 1:10**: "Immediately coming up out of the water, **He** saw the heavens opening, and the Spirit like a dove descending upon **Him**" (emphasis added).  There is no doubt in my mind that both men witnessed these events, however the context would favor Jesus as the "He" in this passage when contrasted with the other Gospels. Christ tells us, **Matt. 11:11**: "Truly I say to you, among those born of women there has not arisen anyone greater than John the Baptist!"

Comment: @Xeno Your "other Gospels" actually go the other way on this and show clearly that it was John (the Baptist) who witnessed these things.  Read John's (the disciple's) account of the event (John 1:32-34).

Comment: @Polyhat I'm not sure if we can ever come to terms on this. Both men "saw the heavens opening..." I read John's account as you suggested. Naturally, he's relating a past event as he witnessed it. Suppose we look at this again: **Mark 1:10**: "[Jesus] Immediately coming up out of the water, He saw the heavens opening..." Why on earth can this not be referring to Jesus? Suppose we rephrase: "As Jesus immediately came up out of the water, He saw the heavens opening..." Do you really think "John" is meant to be inserted there in the text? I don't find that plausible, but you'll probably disagree.

Answer (score 0):

If we allow the Bible to interpret itself, it is plain and clear that John DID in fact see this.  Therefore, we must conclude that the "he" in the verse, while not excluding Jesus (or perhaps others as well), is specifically focused on John.  It seems that John was promised a sign, and God provided this as the sign that indeed this was the Messiah.

> And John bare record, saying, I saw the Spirit descending from heaven
> like a dove, and it abode upon him.
>
> And I knew him not: but he that sent me to baptize with water, the same
> said unto me, Upon whom thou shalt see the Spirit descending, and
> remaining on him, the same is he which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost.
>
> And I saw, and bare record that this is the Son of God. (John 1:32-34)

Grammatically, Mark 1:10 is ambiguous.  The "he" might refer either to John or to Jesus.  Had the writer used "they" in an attempt to include both of them, the third-person plural would actually open the field to potentially include all present.  But that John is the special focus of the text is made clear in this parallel passage from the book of John.  Since John tells us that John had seen this, applying Mark's "he" to Jesus *only* would make the interpretation untrue.